# Outlook won't respond to clicks or keystrokes, but it's not frozen

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

Intermittently, I run into cases where Outlook doesn't respond.  When I say "doesn't respond", I don't mean the usual kind of freeze where it turns grey and says "Not Responding". Instead, it continues to download emails, and to update the Outlook window, but it will not respond to any clicks or keystrokes. Outlook seems to instead treat clicks on the Outlook window, as though I were clicking out of focus, so that Outlook is no longer the active window.

I have tried quick repair, full repair, and windows update. None of these resolve this issue. Has anyone run into a solution to this?

Comment: When it does this, what happens for (1) allowing it to complete downloads and sync (if it is set up to do this, and (2) entering task manager (to end the Outlook task)?

Comment: If you let it complete its downloads, it continues to be unresponsive to clicks. Ending it with task manager causes it to close immediately.

Comment: Is this on Exchange?  Syncing the cache can take a couple of hours on a fast network if the cache has become corrupted somehow. I have not seen this on ordinary Outlook.

Comment: Yeah, it's on Exchange.

Comment: If cache sync was broken (you may have been in a hurry) then it needs to rebuild. That shouldn't cause loss of ability to use the keyboard, but it might.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Outlook safe mode to see if the issue could be resloved?
Besides, as I know, corrupted profile can also lead this issue, so please try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Comment: I have indeed tried creating new profiles, and using safe mode. Both gave the same result.